# Wordpress : display ACF checkbox label on front end

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, label

I have created chekboxes with ACF, now I can display the values ​​of the checkboxes on my front end but I would like to show the associated labels to.

Here is my code :

```
echo "<ul>";
$profession = get_field('profession');
foreach($profession as $key => $check){ 
echo "<li>".$check."</li>";
}; 

echo "</ul>";
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

try this: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field_object/

You can return all the field's metadata with `get_field_object()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if( get_field('field_name') ):
        echo '<div class="class_for_display">';
        echo 'Label:'; echo'<p>'  .the_field('field_name').'</p>';
        echo '</div>';
```

### endif;

i use this code in function.php of child theme